# ecryptfs-mount-private fails silently on Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: ecryptfs

I have a remote linux server running Ubuntu 12.04.4, which I had someone restart. Afterwards I tried ssh'ing in, and found my files encrypted.

Strangely this works:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

But this seems to fail silently:

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

That command basically doesn't seem to say anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I would like to keep using encryption on my server.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you log in via ssh, your home directory is not decrypted.

Unless you see an error message, a command works (rather then failing silently)

After you log in via ssh, you have to manually decrypt your home:

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd ~
```

you will now see your data

```
ls
```

If you wish to automate this , first log in via ssh, then run

```
sudo nano .profile
```

Add these lines and save the file:

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd ~
```

Now you should be able to start a new ssh session, you will be asked your passowrd a second time, and then your data should be decrypted.

There can be other problems with ssh and encrypted home directories, especially getting keys to work.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome

http://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/encrypted-home-directories-ssh-key-authentication